# Can I completely disable the camera functionality in a Lumia 930?

Tags: 8.1, lumia

Is it possible to completely disable the camera functionality so that taking any sort of picture using any app is impossible?

Comment: Are you asking for yourself, or as an admin? It's possible via mobile device management policies.

Comment: @CBHacking as an admin, so that other users cant use the feature, how would I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. But you must be running Windows Phone 8.1 update 2 inorder to do that.

If you are running Windows Phone 8.1 update 2,

1. Go to Settings.
2. Click on App Permissions.
3. Open Camera.
4. Turn it off.

[image: App permissions - Windows Phone 8.1 update 2]

---

**Reference:**

1. [A quick look at Windows Phone 8.1 update 2 - MSPoweruser](http://mspoweruser.com/quick-look-windows-phone-8-1-update-2-lumia-830/)

Answer (score 1):

If you join your Windows 10 Mobile (or 8.1) device to Azure Active Directory (AAD) you can apply a policy to the device (or all company devices) that disables the camera.

Unless you are in the defence industry and your users are onsite on military bases then this is a rather draconian policy. Even most military installations do not disable cameras (was onsite at Dobbs Air force base) and mealy create the expectation that you will be shot if seen taking pictures of anything...

If you disable cameras then how will your users:

- submit receipts
- Scan whiteboards

Comment: Is it possible with Asure Active Directory(AAD) on Windows phone 8.1 too? Cause the question refers to 8.1(see the tag). If possible include that in your answer.